# parse data of certain tag which is before a particular class

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

I need parse data from web page by tag ("p"). I try like this:

```
Elements content = document.getElementsByTag("p");
 for(Element el : content) {
                System.out.println(el.text());

        }
```

And it's work fine. But I get superfluous data. 
For example:

```html
<div class="DicCellTerm">
   <h1>Impossible</h1>
   <div class=des>
      <p class=par2><span class=hint><em>smth</em></span></p>
      <p class=par2>1) (<em>with</em>) all, do</p>
      <p class=par2>2) <span class=hint><em>text</em></span> some words</p>
      <p class=par3>it is impossible</p>
   </div>
</div>
</div><!--DicCell end-->
<div align="center" class="AdContent" id="adcontentnoprint">
<div class=SharedItems>
   <div class=DicCellParent>
      <span class=LinkOtherDic>+ dictionary <strong>impossible</strong> - translate</span>
      <div class=DicCellOther id=diccellothershow>
         <h2><a href='/aljl-ktatlr/liotry-rssian-caar-csr-tdm-799.htm' title="impossible | impossible translate | dictionary">impossible</a></h2>
         <div class=des>
            <p class=par1>1) important, is</p>
            <p class=par1>what</p>
            <p class=par1>2) true, false</p>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!--DicCellOther end-->
   </div>
   <!--DicCellParent end-->
   <div class=DicCellParent>
      <span class=LinkOtherDic>+ translate <strong>important</strong> - dictionary</span>
      <div class=DicCellOther id=diccellothershow>
         <h2><a href='/all-cvdr/dicghnary-rhhan-chtar-ht-hm-800.htm' title="translate">importnant</a></h2>
         <div class=des>
            <p class=par1>1) müim, emiyetli; emiyet bar</p>
            <p class=par1>it is very important - bu pek müimdir, bunıñ büyük emiyeti bar</p>
            <p class=par1>2)  qopayıp, qabarıp</p>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!--DicCellOther end-->
   </div>
   <!--DicCellParent end-->
</div>
<!--SharedItems end-->
```

I need to get data by tag "p" before class SharedItems. 
I tried parse data by class "DicCellTerm" and I get properly data. And all data is written in one line, but I need to get data as on web page.

Comment: Why not to use getElementsByClass​ instead of getElementsByTag and use par2 and par3 classes

Comment: Because i have data which i don't need with classes par2 and par3

Comment: Did you consider using https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax ? to combine the tag name with the class name ? doc.select("p[class^=par]")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Elements elements = document.select(".DicCellTerm p");
```

This grabs all p inside the .DicCellTerm class, then you can iterate over elements. 
Here is a link to all possible selectors in jsoup, this is where i get most of my help =)

https://jsoup.org/apidocs/index.html?org/jsoup/select/Selector.html